# .Net Identity 2 - Facebook Authentication 404 Error

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

When I authenticate on localhost all is well, but as soon as I go to authenticate from the production url, the return path cant be interpreted.

https://domain.com/signin-facebook?code=AQBwYZ2g7eSnxo... results in a generic 404 error.

I'm changing the site url on facebook and don't get any errors from their end.

There's something falling over in Identity that I dont understand I think. Any ideas? Thanks!

Startup.Auth.cs is very simple and looks like:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and also store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider.
        // This is required if your application allows users to login
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login")
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);


        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
           appId: xxxxxxxxxx,
           appSecret: xxxxxxxxxxx;
    }
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem ! Did you find any solution yet ?